# Visual Studio 2013/15 with Emscripten

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, emscripten

I recently tried to use the vs-tool found [here](https://github.com/james-allison/vs-tool/tree/VS2013-Support) done by James Allison.  This works well for the *.html and *.js builds, but it fails for the *.bc builds.  The error message presented is "GCCLIB : error root: rcs: No such file or directory ("rcs" was expected to be an input file, based on the commandline arguments provided)" which i have no idea what it means, and googling the error does not yield any results.

Any thoughts or ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Open the .vcxproj file for the project in a text editor and see if under the emscripten build configurations there are tags that are not relevant.

For example I had a "ResourceCompile" tag which always led to an error regarding rc.exe being missing.
Similarly I also had "BrowseInformation" tags.

This happens when you create your Emscripten configuration from an configuration which had these additional tags for example x64. Probably a bug in vs-tools. Ideally it should be skipping these tags.